# accessing double pointer 2d array passed by reference to a function

Tags: c, pointers

i've this data structure

```
struct m_bucket
{
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

then i need to use a 2D array of `struct m_bucket` as a matrix so i declare it on this way

```
typedef struct m_bucket **  matrix_t;
```

and this is the initialization function

```
matrix_t matrix_alloc( int n_rows , int n_cols )
{
   matrix_t m;
   int i;

    m = ( struct m_bucket **) malloc( ((n_rows + 1) * sizeof(  struct m_bucket  * )));

    for(i=0 ; i < (n_rows + 1) ; i++ )
    {
        m[i] = ( struct m_bucket *) malloc( ((n_cols + 1) * sizeof(  struct m_bucket )));
    }

   return m;
}
```

my problem is that i'm a bit confused about the right way to acces this data structure when          passing it by reference to a function.
I tried this but it isn't working.

```
void matrix_set_column(matrix_t * matrix , int val , int col , int n_cols)
{ 
int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < (n_cols + 1) ; i++)
    {   
        (*matrix)[col][i].cost = val;

        if (val>0)
            ((*matrix)[col][i]).a =  4;
        else
            ((*matrix)[col][i]).a = -1;
        val++;
    }

   }
```

what's the right way to access this structure?

Comment: If you want to pass it by value, then you can use ------void matrix_set_column(matrix_t  matrix...)-------.And if by reference then use --------void matrix_set_column(matrix_t * matrix......)--

Comment: i want to pass it by reference and ,indeed , i'm using void matrix_set_column(matrix_t * matrix , int val , int col , int n_cols)

Comment: In C it is not necessary to cast results of `malloc` before the assignment. This should save you some typing :)

Comment: I cannot locate the function call to "matrix_set_column" in the code.
Do provide that so that we can get an idea about the arguments that
you have passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code that allocates `matrix_t` uses the number of rows `n_rows` for the first `malloc`, the code that uses the matrix needs to pass indexes in the order `row`, then `column`. Your function needs to reverse its indexes, like this:

```
// Assuming that col represents the column, not the row,
// i represents the row, so it needs to go first
((*matrix)[i][col]).a =  4;
```

Index `i` needs to from zero to `n_rows+1`, too.

Other than that, your code is fine: you have correctly added parentheses to force unary `*` to complete before `[]` operator, so the rest of the code is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the following:

```
void matrix_set_column(matrix_t matrix , int val , int col , int n_cols)
{ 
int i;

  for(i = 0 ; i < (n_cols + 1) ; i++)
  {   
    matrix[col][i].cost = val;

    if (val>0)
        matrix[col][i].a =  4;
    else
        matrix[col][i].a = -1;
    val++;
  }

}
```

and use it as:

```
...
matrix_t m;
m = matrix_alloc(10,20);
matrix_set_column(m, 123, 9, 20);
...
```

This will pass only pointers, because `matrix_t` is a pointer type.

Comment: OP wants to pass the matrix by reference.

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey is any pass by reference in `C`?

Comment: @AbhishekChoubey This is why I put "you probably wanted...". I suppose that he basically wants that values assigned in `matrix_set_column` are actually assigned in the matrix allocated in the main program and passed as a parameter (which sounds as a call by reference).

Comment: @Jayesh I got the the answer. Though I've seen a lots of comments from different people on SO that there's no pass by reference in C, but I never got a convincing answer for that until now. But now I understand that pass by reference is "simulated" in C. :-).